# How to use @index from outer #each as array key in inner #each in Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When I have structure of data that I pass to Handlebars template:

```
{ a: ['name 1'], b: [[1,2,3]] }
```

And I have the following loop:

```
{{#each a}}
  Hello, {{this}}!
  Your scores are:
  {{#each ../b[@index_of_a]}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

**How to use current elements index of loop `{{#each a}}` (let's name it XXX to get element of array `b`: `b[XXX]`?**

Comment: {{#each ../b[../@index]}} does it not work?

Comment: @artgb I'm getting error with this code `Error: Parse error on line 34:
...each ../a[../@index
----------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of Handlebars library, you can achieve this using in-built **lookup** helper.

```
{{#each a}}
  Hello, {{this}}!
  {{#each (lookup ../b @index)}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```